# Why colab notebook does not recognise a file in a set working directory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, netcdf4

I tried running a python script using the following methods:

- locally using both spyder and the command prompts windows for anaconda & cmd
- then I used google colab notebook

Basically, I uploaded all the .nc files to my google drive plus an excel file with some data that are needed in the code. The code stops at some point and returns an error message saying that there is no such file although clearly the files is there.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Precipitations') # to set a new working directory

date_range=pd.date_range(start="19960101", end="20200930")
df = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Precipitations/stationssa.xlsx')df1=pd.DataFrame(0,columns=df.loc[:,"NAME"],index=date_range)

for position in stations:
    lat_station = df.iloc[position,1]
    lon_station = df.iloc[position,2]
    for day in date_range:
        data = Dataset("gpcp_v01r03_daily_d"+str(day)[0:4]+str(day)[5:7]+str(day)[8:10]+".nc")
        prcp=data.variables['precip'][:]
        lon_data = data.variables['longitude'][:]
        lat_data = data.variables['latitude'][:]
        sq_diff_lat = (lat_data - lat_station)**2
        sq_diff_lon = (lon_data - lon_station)**2
        min_index_lat = sq_diff_lat.argmin()
        min_index_lon = sq_diff_lon.argmin()
        if type(prcp[0, min_index_lat, min_index_lon])==np.ma.core.MaskedConstant:
            df1.loc[str(day),position] = -1
        else:
            df1.loc[str(day),position] = float(prcp[0, min_index_lat, min_index_lon])
df1=df1.replace(-1,np.nan) ### when the dataframe is done
df1.to_csv("Preciptations.csv") ## to export to a csv file
```

The  link  to the  colab  notebook  is here:
<https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q5e1nuVHfPJsKba2ImoBv456aoO9gu0s?usp=sharing

But I get this error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZIsH.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount your drive first, using

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```